# When (inner) joining to a subquery, does it make any difference which comes first?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I'm joining the `employees` table to a subquery of the `departments` table. So it could either look something like this (with the subquery on the right of the JOIN):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `employees` e 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ... FROM `departments` 
    WHERE ... GROUP BY ...
) AS d ON e.`department_id` = d.`department_id`
WHERE ....
```

OR... it could look something like this (with the subquery on the left of the JOIN):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM `departments` 
    WHERE ... GROUP BY ...
) AS d 
INNER JOIN `employees` e ON e.`department_id` = d.`department_id`
WHERE ....
```

Does it make any difference? Is one slightly more efficient than the other? Or are they exactly the same?

Comment: Agreed with xdazz use explain to see the difference if any.

Comment: Yes, the order in which tables or inline views appear in the `FROM` clause decide the driving table, i.e., table which starts the chain of joining. The result doesn't matter much, as `a INTERSECTION b ~ b INTERSECTION a`, but driving tables impact performance. You have to try and check which performs better.